# Skip reading a file if it just has headers and continue reading rest of the files with headers + data, with a MultiResourceItemReader?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, filereader

Is it possible to skip reading a file if it just has headers and continue reading rest of the files with headers + data, with a `MultiResourceItemReader`?

I have multiple files to be read and following is my configuration. With my configuration in `SingleFileReader`, I am skipping the headers, but not the files with headers, and I am getting a `FlatFileParseException` at line: 2 with `input=[]` as there is no data to be read.

The code works fine if there are any number of files with headers and data.

```
<bean id="multiResourceReader"
    class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="file:${file.path}"/>
    <property name="delegate" ref="SingleFileReader" />
    <property name="strict" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="SingleFileReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
             <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter"  value=","/>
                    <property name="names" value="${field.names}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.test.ItemMapper"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: how you can detect a file has header and another one not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Abhishek is right, but - **if you can decide if a 1st line is an header or not in some way** - you can:

1. set `linesToSkip` property to 0
2. Write a custom `LineMapper` where you decide if the line should be skipped or processed using delegation.

Skipping an header is done during processing phase

```
class MyLineMapper implements LineMapper<Object> {
  LineMapper<?> delegate;

  Object mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) {
    if(line is header) {
      return new LineToSkip(line, lineNumber);
    }
    return delegate.mapLine(line, lineNumber);
  }
}
```

`MyLineMapper.delegate` is populated with the line mapper you have configured in your current job XML file.
As next step write a custom processor where you filter out `LineToSkip` objects and inject this processor into your current processors chain using a `CompositeItemProcessor`.

Comment: Thanks Luca, I have implemented a FaltFileItemReader and overwrote the doRead() method to return null if there is a parsing error at line 2 with input[] and if not any other exceptions will be rethrown. Not sure if this is a clean way though.

Answer (score 0):

When we say reading with 'MultiResourceItemReader', we should understand that reading multiple files with same structure.

Below is the code snippet on how to configure MultiResourceItemReader:

```
<bean id="multiResourceReader" class="org.spr...MultiResourceItemReader">
   <property name="resources" value="classpath:data/input/file-*.txt" />
   <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
</bean>
```

Here we are reading all the .txt files from the same location and we are using a singe item reader thats mentioned as delegate. Please refer to the following link for more detail http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html

In your case, since you have few files with headers and few files without header, you will have to use multiple readers and then process the data.